Tusdotnet direct upload to Google Drive
is it possible to upload using tus and store data directly to Google Drive? I am using uppy on the client and tusdotnet on the server. I have tried implement a Custom ITusStore but didnt work
public async Task<string> CreateFileAsync(long uploadLength, string metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var uploadId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Google Drive file metadata
        var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
        {
            Name = $"tus_upload_{uploadId}",
            Parents = new[] { "parent_folder_id" } // Replace with your folder ID
        };

        // Create resumable upload session
        var uploadRequest = _driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata, null, "application/octet-stream");
        uploadRequest.Fields = "id";
        uploadRequest.ChunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB chunks

        // The UploadUri is the resumable session endpoint
        var uploadUri = uploadRequest.InitiateSessionAsync(cancellationToken).Result;

        _uploadSessions[uploadId] = new UploadSession
        {
            UploadUri = uploadUri,
            Offset = 0
        };

        return uploadId;
    }

